# Unable to produce messages to Kafka with SSL enabled

Tags: security, ssl, apache-kafka

I configured kafka (1.0) with SSL enabled and added listeners property as `listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092,SSL://:9093`
And Advertised listeners as `advertisted.listeners=PLAINTEXT://PUBLICIP:9092,SSL://PUBLICIP:9093`

I am able to produce messages with 9092 port, but unable to do so on SSL enabled 9093. Below is the error I am getting

```
[2018-05-03 10:51:41,990] ERROR Error when sending message to topic test with key: null, value: 16 bytes with error: (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.ErrorLoggingCallback)
```

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.

Here is the producer command I am using

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list PUBLICIP1:9093,PUBLICIP2:9093,PUBLICIP3:9093 --topic test --property security.protocol=SSL --producer.config ~/client.properties
```

Here are the entries in client.properties

```
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/home/ubuntu/kafka.client.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=trustpassword
```

Comment: You need to enable debug logging or even ssl debug logging to proceed further here. The problem could be server side, client side, or in your certificates still. I suggest you follow a tutorial like https://docs.confluent.io/current/tutorials/security_tutorial.html This way you'll know if you missed any steps along the way as it looks like you are generating your own certs anyway.

Comment: If you think all keystores and certificates are valid and properly setup in brokers then try to add client key store along with trust store in your properties file. Also check the ssl.cipher.suites property on broker and have the same in your producer ssl properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you use 2.0+ versions below is the command for console producer

```
kafka-console-producer –broker-list kafka.example.com:9093 –topic securing-kafka –producer.config /etc/kafka/producer_ssl.properties
```

producer_ssl.properties

```
bootstrap.servers=kafka.example.com:9093
security.protocol=SSL
ssl.truststore.location=/etc/security/tls/kafka.client.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=test1234
ssl.keystore.location=/etc/security/tls/kafka.client.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=test1234
ssl.key.password=test1234
```